# Add exception details to an ErrorController

Tags: java, spring

I have the following error controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        model.addAttribute("status", status);
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Other than getting the error status above, is there a way to show a default error template page for debugging purposes with Spring?  If not, what are some of the common values I may want to display, for example:

- URL requested
- Params sent
- Exception type
- Exception message
- Stacktrace

Comment: Look at exception hadnler methods for Spring MVC. It allows to intercept any type of exception that you say to it. You can just specify Exception if you want to catch all the exceptions.
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @Bogdan -- how would I get the "Exception" variable to pass to my template, when I add `Exception ex` to my `handleError` method, it is null.

Comment: How are you going to call this "/error" endpoint? Should it be called from somwherr in case of error? @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) annotations on non-endpoint methods tell Spring to call this methods when an exception appears. Instance of Exception is injected by Spring.

Comment: @Bogdan by typing in a url, such as localhost:80080/page-should-404, and testing the responses, for example.

Comment: Ok. Then I would put such a method to you controller (instead of the one with endpoint that you have) and try it. Looks like you need example which returns ModelAndView in the article.